# Converting EBNF to Regular Expression

Tags: regex, bnf, ebnf

I need to convert the following EBNF to a regular expression that will match any valid format string. For example '<8','*^10','+6','15,.2', etc.

```
<spec> -> :[[<fill>]<align>][<sign>][<width>][,][.<prec>]
<fill> -> <character> (* i.e., any one character)
<align> -> < | > | = | ^
<sign> -> + | - | ' '
<width> -> <integer> (* i.e, one or more digits 0....9  *)
<prec> -> <integer>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried

Answer (score 0):

If the regex engine supports named capturing groups (f.e. PCRE) then this could work:

```
^((?<fill>.?)(?<align>[<>=^]))?(?<sign>[ +\-]?)(?<width>[0-9]+)[,]?(?:[.](?<prec>[0-9]+))?$
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/ILbsNz/1)

Note that most is optional, except for the "width" capturing group.  It's an assumption based on the fact that the "width" exists in all examples.

Using unnamed capturing groups, the regex becomes shorter:

```
^((.?)([<>=^]))?([ +\-]?)([0-9]+)[,]?(?:[.]([0-9]+))?$
```